# ExtJS Grid storing Cell State automagically

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs

I am porting quite a huge piece of software to an ExtJS Grid. Lots of data (and I mean lots of data) is loaded on-demand into spans that are placed inside grid's cells.

Imagine grid cells having `<span id="foo_bar'></span>` as content, and special ajax handlers are polling the backend for updated information and once available the spans are filled with it.

Now, in case I collapse some part of the grid and then re-exand them again I loose all automatically filled cell content, and am left with empty spans (which I started from in the first place).

I know the correct way is to setup a store and push all data into the store. But as I've mentioned above: I am porting quite a huge piece of legacy software to ExtJS, and I do not really have much choice here.

Is there a way to automagically push grid cell values to the store?

**Update:**

A grid is loaded with, suppose, 2000 cells (this can vary tremendously). Every cell contains various grades of HTML, mostly this is , but this can be pretty much anything (including several spans or divs in one cell). In the background there is a comet process pushing new data to the HTML page almost in real time. This data is populated to the corresponding SPANS and DIVs either based on their IDs or class or both.

What I want to achieve is that either: 
  a) the model for the grid is atomagically updated with the new html content of the cells (how can I achieve this)?
  b) when collapsing/expanding tree's nodes the model data is NOT reloaded afresh.

Is either a or b possible? if so — how?

Answer (score 0):

Just update your store when the 'special ajax handlers' successfully return values. In staid of manually messing with the dom.

so in the success callback do something like -> [loadData()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData)

**Edit:**

Seems like you are working with very bad legacy code :) If adding a simple line of code to the ajax handler is a tremendous effort.. You can however attach dom listeners, but it's very bad practice. [Here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-event-DOMSubtreeModified) are some events to listen to

**Edit:**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/nRwGM/3/) is an example of the use of how you could listen to dom events, it's rather a pure js solution but, meh.. it works..

Comment: Unfortunately that is not easy to do (the effort is tremendous).

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to create a listener for all the cells in the grid? Once the content of some cell changes it should automatically update store? If possible, then how?

Comment: Is that what you where looking for? Else, can you show some of your code?

Comment: Yeah, that would solve it. There is no question related and Grid Related code to show, as the software package is HUGE... 40K lines of JavaScript code access DOM elements directly :(

Comment: loadData( data, [append] ) will not work here, as it needs a "data" parameter which I will need to cook beforehand == lots of trouble

Comment: data is a simple record(s)...shouldn't be that complicated: can be added like this `loadData([{id: 'foo_bar', 'field1': 'someValue' }],true);` so preparing the data var doesn't seem too complicated to me... depending on the complexity of you model of course.. What do you want to put in the store? You got to put it in somehow...

Comment: my problem is that every cell contains different span elements (with god knows how many different CSS classes et cetera), so cooking the whole dataset is not as easy as I'd like it to be ;-) is there really no way to simply "watch" DOM elements change?

Comment: yes! I covered the watching part.. just attach a handler for the right [DOMevent](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-event-DOMCharacterDataModified) but once it's triggered, I was under the impression you want to put 'something' (like some of the content of the span) in a store..

Comment: Oh wait I think I get it. You want to put the whole content of the span with all it's children in a store? Again bad idea... but hell, it's not like the rest looks very thought out.. just create a store, with a model having 1 field 'html' for example and pump the html strings into the store with: `loadData([{html: '<span>foo<span>bar</span>stuff</span>'}]);`

Comment: Not just the content of the span, but also the span itself... I have updated the question with a more thorough description :) I am also failing to understand how to use DOMCharacterDataModified in that matter, how do I determine what part of the model I update?